# GeoServer - Polygon Label

Tags: geoserver, polygon, labeling

I would like to change place of polygon label to X place:

[image]

Which function should I use?
 doesn’t change the position. The label is still in the centere of polygon..

```
<se:Rule>
  <se:MinScaleDenominator>1</se:MinScaleDenominator>
  <se:MaxScaleDenominator>25000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
  <se:TextSymbolizer>
    <se:Label>
      <ogc:PropertyName>kod_reb</ogc:PropertyName>
    </se:Label>
    <se:Font>
      <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Times New Roman</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">10</se:SvgParameter>
    </se:Font>
    <se:LabelPlacement>
      <se:PointPlacement>
        <se:AnchorPoint>
          <se:AnchorPointX>0.5</se:AnchorPointX>
          <se:AnchorPointY>0.5</se:AnchorPointY>
        <se:Displacement>
            <se:DisplacementX>-25</se:DisplacementX>
            <se:DisplacementY>-25</se:DisplacementY>
        </se:Displacement>
        </se:AnchorPoint> 
      </se:PointPlacement>
    </se:LabelPlacement>
    <se:Halo>
      <se:Radius>1</se:Radius>
      <se:Fill>
        <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
      </se:Fill>
    </se:Halo>
    <se:Fill>
      <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
    </se:Fill>
  </se:TextSymbolizer>
</se:Rule>
```

---

o Can you tell me what is wrong? :(

```
<se:Rule>
  <se:MinScaleDenominator>1</se:MinScaleDenominator>
  <se:MaxScaleDenominator>25000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
  <se:TextSymbolizer>
    <se:Label>
      <ogc:PropertyName>kod_reb</ogc:PropertyName>
    </se:Label>
    <se:Font>
      <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Times New Roman</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">10</se:SvgParameter>
    </se:Font>
    <se:LabelPlacement>
      <se:PointPlacement>
        <se:AnchorPoint>
          <se:AnchorPointX>0.5</se:AnchorPointX>
          <se:AnchorPointY>0.5</se:AnchorPointY>
        <se:Displacement>
            <se:DisplacementX>-25</se:DisplacementX>
            <se:DisplacementY>-25</se:DisplacementY>
        </se:Displacement>
        </se:AnchorPoint> 
      </se:PointPlacement>
    </se:LabelPlacement>
    <se:Halo>
      <se:Radius>1</se:Radius>
      <se:Fill>
        <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
      </se:Fill>
    </se:Halo>
    <se:Fill>
      <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
    </se:Fill>
  </se:TextSymbolizer>
</se:Rule>
```

Comment: Changing Displacement value doesn't change anything :/

Answer (score 0):

There may be something else wrong with your style as

```
       <LabelPlacement>
          <PointPlacement>
            <AnchorPoint>
              <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
              <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
            </AnchorPoint>
            <Displacement>
              <DisplacementX>-25</DisplacementX>
              <DisplacementY>-25</DisplacementY>
              </Displacement>
            
          </PointPlacement>
        </LabelPlacement>
```

works for me:

[image]